# Permutations with exactly $k$ inversions

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $I_{n,k}$ denotes the number of permutations of $\left\{1,..,n\right\}$ that have exactly $k$ inversions. Prove that:
>   $$\sum_k I_{n,k}x^k = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x^i)}{(1-x)^n}$$

The only one fact I came up with is recursive formula $I_{n,k}=\sum_{i=0}^{}I_{n-1,i}$, but it's rather useless here, I think.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any permutation $\tau$, we denote the number of inverse pairs in $(\tau(1),\tau(i)),(\tau(2),\tau(i)),...,(\tau(i-1),\tau(i))$ by $V(\tau,i)$. Then $\tau\rightarrow (V(\tau,1),V(\tau,2),...,V(\tau,n))$ is a bijection from permutations to $n$-tuples with $a_i \le i-1$, with number of inversions correspond to sum of all coordinates. Expand the RHS and you see it is the generating function for the number of such tuples, while the LHS is counting permutations with a given number of inversions.